# How to iterate sibling nodes through XSL?

Tags: xslt

I have an xml which looks like :

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<siteMap>
    <siteMapNode>
        <siteMapNode url="/personal/" >
            <siteMapNode url="/personal/abc/" title="abc" >
                <siteMapNode url="/personal/abc/xyz" title="abc" />
                <siteMapNode url="/personal/abc/pqr" title="pqr" />
            </siteMapNode>
             <siteMapNode url="/personal/opq/" title="abc" >
                <siteMapNode url="/personal/opq/xyz" title="abc" />
                <siteMapNode url="/personal/opq/pqr" title="pqr" />
            </siteMapNode>
        </siteMapNode>
        <siteMapNode url="/reasonal/" >
            <siteMapNode url="/reasonal/abc/" title="abc" >
                <siteMapNode url="/reasonal/abc/xyz" title="abc" />
                <siteMapNode url="/reasonal/abc/pqr" title="pqr" />
            </siteMapNode>
             <siteMapNode url="/reasonal/opq/" title="abc" >
                <siteMapNode url="/reasonal/opq/xyz" title="abc" />
                <siteMapNode url="/reasonal/opq/pqr" title="pqr" />
            </siteMapNode>
        </siteMapNode>
    </siteMapNode>
</siteMap>
```

What I wish to do is iterate through whole xml to check which node matches my url and then loop through its siblings. For example, check for "/reasonal/opq/pqr" and then get title of both `<siteMapNode url="/reasonal/opq/xyz" title="abc" />` and `<siteMapNode url="/reasonal/opq/pqr" title="pqr" />` in an li.

I have never written xsl before. Based on learnings so far, I can loop all nodes and check for url match, but not sure how can i put its siblings including it the node in li. Can someone help with some code.

Comment: Can you show your expected output in the case where the URL is "/reasonal/opq/pqr"? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you would probably start off by defining a parameter so that the url can be passed to the XSLT

```
<xsl:param name="url" select="'/reasonal/opq/pqr'" />
```

In this case, I have defined a default value of '/reasonal/opq/pqr' should no parameter passed.

Then, to select the **siteMapNode** elements with a matching **url** attribute, you would do the following:

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="//siteMapNode[@url=$url]" />
```

There are a couple of ways to get the siblings of this matching **siteMapNode**. If you wanted to get all siblings including the current element, you could simply do this

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="../siteMapNode" mode="list" />
```

(Note, the mode="list" is because you will end up with two templates matching **siteMapNode** and so you need to distinguish between them).

If you don't want to include the current element, you could do either of the following:

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="../siteMapNode[generate-id() != generate-id(current())]" 
     mode="list" />

<xsl:apply-templates select="preceding-sibling::siteMapNode
     |following-sibling::siteMapNode" 
     mode="list" />
```

Here is the full XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
   <xsl:output indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>
   <xsl:param name="url" select="'/reasonal/opq/pqr'"/>

   <xsl:template match="/">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="//siteMapNode[@url=$url]"/>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="siteMapNode">
      <ul>
         <xsl:apply-templates select="../siteMapNode" mode="list"/>
      </ul>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="siteMapNode" mode="list">
      <li>
         <a href="{@url}">
            <xsl:value-of select="@title"/>
         </a>
      </li>
   </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When applied to your sample XML, the following is output

```
<ul>
   <li>
      <a href="/reasonal/opq/xyz">abc</a>
   </li>
   <li>
      <a href="/reasonal/opq/pqr">pqr</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```